# QML and C++ connection issue in socket programming

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, qml

I want to send a UDP packet from server to client. I wrote the server/client code in C++ without problems. But when I send a message to QML signal little problem arise.

myudp.cpp class code:

```
#include "myudp.h"
MyUDP::MyUDP(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
socket = new QUdpSocket(this);
socket->bind(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 5824);
connect(socket,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this, SLOT(readyRead()));
}

// send message in client mode
void MyUDP::SayHello()
{
    QByteArray Data;
    Data.append("test message");
    socket->writeDatagram(Data,QHostAddress::LocalHost,5824);
    // 192.168.0.100
}

void MyUDP::readyRead()
{
    QByteArray Buffer;
    Buffer.resize(socket->pendingDatagramSize());;

    QHostAddress sender;
    quint16 senderPort;

    socket->readDatagram(Buffer.data(),Buffer.size(), &sender, &senderPort);    
    qDebug()<< "Message:" << Buffer;
    setType(Buffer);
}

QByteArray MyUDP::type()
{
    return _type;
}

void MyUDP::setType(const QByteArray &t)
{
    _type = t;
    emit typeChanged();
}
```

myudp.h

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QUdpSocket>

class MyUDP : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QByteArray type READ type WRITE setType NOTIFY typeChanged)
public:
    explicit MyUDP(QObject *parent = 0);
    void SayHello();

    QByteArray type();
    void setType(const QByteArray &t);

signals:
    void typeChanged();

public slots:
    void readyRead();

private:
    QUdpSocket *socket;
    QByteArray _type;
};
```

myudp class defined for both client and server side.

main.c in client side:

```
#include "qtquick1applicationviewer.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include "myudp.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QtQuick1ApplicationViewer viewer;
    viewer.addImportPath(QLatin1String("modules"));
    viewer.setOrientation(QtQuick1ApplicationViewer::ScreenOrientationAuto);
    viewer.setMainQmlFile(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml"));
    viewer.showExpanded();

        MyUDP client;
        client.SayHello();

    return app.exec();
}
```

main.c in server side that connected to qml:

```
#include "qtquick1applicationviewer.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDeclarativeEngine>
#include <QDeclarativeComponent>
#include <QDebug>
#include "myudp.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{       
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<MyUDP>("MyUDP", 1,0, "MyUDP");
    QDeclarativeEngine engine;
    QDeclarativeComponent component(&engine, QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
    MyUDP *myUDP = qobject_cast<MyUDP *>(component.create());    

    QtQuick1ApplicationViewer viewer;
    viewer.addImportPath(QLatin1String("modules"));
    viewer.setOrientation(QtQuick1ApplicationViewer::ScreenOrientationAuto);
    viewer.setMainQmlFile(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml"));
    viewer.showExpanded();

    return app.exec();
}
```

and finally main.qml in server side:

```
import QtQuick 1.1
import MyUDP 1.0

Rectangle {    
    width: 360
    height: 360    

    Text {
        id: txt
        text: qsTr("Hello World")
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }

    MyUDP{
        id: myUdp
        onTypeChanged: {
            txt.text = "recived msg:" + type;
            console.log("recived massage is " + type)
        }
    }
}
```

I send message from client to server and server recieve message correctly in c++ zone, after that I send this message to QML. in QML `console.log("recived massage is " + type)` correctly print message data but `txt.text = "recived msg:" + type;` not triggered and nothing show in text file.
I'm confused why this happens!!

Comment: With UDP and `sendto()` the one thing this cannot possibly be is a connection issue.

Comment: Why are you loading main.qml twice ? i.e using QDeclarativeEngine and QtQuick1ApplicationViewer